# Conditional sentence 'elif i=='Z' ' which is Invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
def password():
    while True:
        try:
            A = input()
            B = []
            for i in A:
                if i.isdigit():
                    B.append(i)
                elif i.isupper() and i != 'Z':
                    B.append(chr(ord(i.lower())+1)
                elif i == 'Z':                                 'invalid syntax'
                    B.append('a')
                else:
                    if i in 'abc':
                        B.append('2')
                    elif i in 'def':
                        B.append('3')
                    elif i in 'ghi':
                        B.append('4')
                    elif i in 'jkl':
                        B.append('5')
                    elif i in 'mno':
                        B.append('6')
                    elif i in 'pqrs':
                        B.append('7')
                    elif i in 'tuv':
                        B.append('8')
                    elif i in 'wxyz':
                        B.append('9')
            print(''.join(B))
        except:
            break
```

Where I have problem at 'else if i == 'Z'', I don't know what's wrong. I have tried to # that line, but the problem will goto the next elif

Answer (score 4):

```
#       1   2   3       4      <- open
B.append(chr(ord(i.lower())+1)
#                        12  3 <- close
```

Not enough closing parentheses, which affects the next line. Just add a `)` to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```py
B.append(chr(ord(i.lower())+1)
```

Append doesn't have a closing parenthesis